# How can I access ghost admin?

Tags: nginx, admin, digital-ocean, ghost

I installed ghost on my digital ocean droplets as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-blog-with-ghost-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

The problem is that when I can't access the admin with http://my-ghost-blog.com/ghost/editor/. It only displays my blog home page. 
In addition, when I navigate on the site (for example I go to a blog post), the url does not update, it's always http://my-ghost-blog.com/

How can I solve this problem?

Maybe it comes from the fact that I use [Freenom](http://www.freenom.com/), a free domain name provider; and maybe it does not redirect the full url path?

Answer (score 4):

You should have updated config.js file with your domain url for production environment.

Comment: I can't check if you're right anymore. This issue was due to url redirect and bad configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with another domain name provider (not free) and it works.